# Problema com v-col Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, grid, vuetify

Olá[image: 1]]
Estou tendo um problema com relação ao sistema de gride do vuetify. Eu estou utilizando o lg para visualização na minha máquina, entretanto quando utilizo xs ou sm para dispositivos móveis não está dando nenhum efeito.

Na resolução da minha máquina está funcionando perfeitamente o lg, entretanto o problema está nos dispositivos móveis. Pretendo colocar a logo em uma linha e a barra de pesquisa na outra, assim cada um ocupando 12 colunas.

Alguma luz?

Agradeço, desde já.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<template>
  <v-row>
    <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4" lg="3" offset-lg="1">
      <v-card class="pa-2" outlined tile>Card 1</v-card>
    </v-col>

    <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4" lg="3" offset-lg="1">
      <v-card class="pa-2" style="background-color: lightgrey;">Card 2</v-card>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</template>
```

Utiliza cols="12"....